$p$-adic solenoid $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[1/p], \mathbb{S}^1)$
I'm trying to characterize the $p$-adic solenoid $\mathbb{T}_p = \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[1/p], \mathbb{S}^1)$.
If I'm not mistaken, any character $\chi$ of $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ can be written as $\chi_{x, y}(t) = \exp(2\pi i t \, (x + y))$, where $x$ is a real number and $y$ is a $p$-adic integer ($x$ is chosen by looking at $\chi(1)$ and $y$ is uniquely determined through the values $\chi\bigl(\frac{1}{p^k}\bigr)$ as $k$ ranges through $\mathbb{N}$).
Even though the sum $x + y$ is not well-defined in the usual sense, it makes sense to "multiply" it by elements of $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ in the complex exponential, since given $\frac{a}{p^n} \in \mathbb{Z}[1/p]$, only a finite number of terms will be non-integers in the expression $\frac{a}{p^n} y$.
This gives us a surjective continuous group homomorphism $$
f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{T}_p \\
(x, y) \mapsto \chi_{x, y}
$$
($\mathbb{T}_p$ is really seen as the Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ with the discrete topology, so it has the topology of pointwise convergence).
The issue I'm having has to do with the kernel of this map. If I'm not mistaken, the $p$-adic solenoid is supposed to be isomorphic to
$$\frac{\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{Z}_p}{\mathbb{Z}},$$
where $\mathbb{Z}$ embeds diagonally as a discrete subgroup. However, the kernel of this map $f$ seems to be $\mathbb{Z} \times {0}$:
If $\chi_{x, y}(t) = 1$ for all $t \in \mathbb{Z}[1/p]$, then in particular, $\exp(2\pi i \,(x + y)) = 1 = \exp(2 \pi i \, x)$, since $y$ is a $p$-adic integer, and this implies that $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and can be removed from the exponential expression.
At the same time, we have $\exp(2\pi i \frac{1}{p^n}y) = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, which means that $\frac{y}{p^n} \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and forces $y$ to be zero, and we get that $\ker(f) = \mathbb{Z} \times 0$. I know for a fact that this doesn't make any sense, since the quotient by $\ker(f)$ would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{Z}_p$, which is compact, and would therefore give an actual isomorphism of topological groups
$$\mathbb{T}_p \cong \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{Z}_p$$
which is absurd, since not only is $\mathbb{T}_p$ connected, it is also $p$-torsion free (since $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ is discrete and $p$-divisible), so this isomorphism can't hold topologically nor algebraically.
I would like to know where the error lies.

I follow your argument up to and including the point where you show that for $(x,y) \in ker(f)$, we have $x \in \mathbb Z$. But now let me ask you, what is $f(x,-x)$ for any $x\in \mathbb Z$?
From there, I think you'll see what the kernel is, and how it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. I think the subtle error is in the phrase, "that $x\in \mathbb Z$ can be removed from the exponential expression".
